# firebase | Verify ID tokens using a third-party JWT library

Tags: java, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

Attempting to validate firebase id tokens using jjwt. Using GoogleCredential class to pull the private key. But I'm not sure if that's correct. Receiving an error: `JWT signature does not match locally computed signature.`Am I supposed to be using the private key here from service account json? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what ...setSigningKey(...) takes in.

```java
@Service
public class FirebaseAuthVerifier implements AuthVerifier {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseAuthVerifier.class);

    @Autowired
    private FirebaseProperties fbProps;

    public boolean verify(AuthToken token) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        // get google credential
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/service-account.json");
        ByteArrayOutputStream streamCopy = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteStreams.copy(stream, streamCopy);
        stream.close();

        GoogleCredential gc = GoogleCredential.fromStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(streamCopy.toByteArray()),
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance());

        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(gc.getServiceAccountPrivateKey()).parse(token.getTokenId());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // log
            logger.info("Firebase auth token verification error: ");
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
            // claims may have been tampered with
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right lines! The key from the service account is used when creating JWTs to send to Google/Firebase. You really don't want to put that in your APK, as any malicious individual could steal it and use it to create ID tokens as you!

When you're validating a token from Firebase, you need to check Firebase's own keys - luckily, these are public! You can grab them from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com - they rotate every few hours. If you look in that file you'll see it's a JSON dictionary, like this:

```
"8226146523a1b8894ba03ad525667b9475d393f5": "---CERT---",
```

The key in this is the `kid` field in the header of the ID token JWT - it corresponds to the key the token was signed with, meaning the cert that corresponds can be used to verify the signature.

Take a look at the (server side) docs for [validating ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) for more.

Comment: I gotcha, I was thinking maybe the claim verification would check the keyId. I'll check that out. Storing the private key, is just for development purposes, I'll make sure to remove and remake once things get rolling.

Comment: I got it going! Posted my code in another answer below, in-case you'd like to check it out. Thank you again (:

Answer (score 1):

Using custom jwt id token validation

```java
@Service
public class FirebaseAuthVerifier implements AuthVerifier {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseAuthVerifier.class);
    private static final String pubKeyUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com";

    /**
     *
     * @param token
     * @return
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public boolean verify(AuthToken token) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        // get public keys
        JsonObject publicKeys = getPublicKeysJson();

        // verify count
        int size = publicKeys.entrySet().size();
        int count = 0;

        // get json object as map
        // loop map of keys finding one that verifies
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: publicKeys.entrySet()) {
            // log
            logger.info("attempting jwt id token validation with: ");

            try {
                // trying next key
                count++;

                // get public key
                PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(entry);

                // validate claim set
                Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(publicKey).parse(token.getTokenId());

                // success, we can return
                return true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // log
                logger.info("Firebase id token verification error: ");
                logger.info(e.getMessage());
                // claims may have been tampered with
                // if this is the last key, return false
                if (count == size) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // no jwt exceptions
        return true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param entry
     * @return
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    private PublicKey getPublicKey(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String publicKeyPem = entry.getValue().getAsString()
                .replaceAll("-----BEGIN (.*)-----", "")
                .replaceAll("-----END (.*)----", "")
                .replaceAll("\r\n", "")
                .replaceAll("\n", "")
                .trim();

        logger.info(publicKeyPem);

        // generate x509 cert
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(entry.getValue().getAsString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inputStream);

        return cert.getPublicKey();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private JsonObject getPublicKeysJson() throws IOException {
        // get public keys
        URI uri = URI.create(pubKeyUrl);
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(uri);
        HttpTransport http = new NetHttpTransport();
        HttpResponse response = http.createRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(url).execute();

        // store json from request
        String json = response.parseAsString();
        // disconnect
        response.disconnect();

        // parse json to object
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

        return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had missed this was a self-answer. In future, flag the post not the comment, and keep the tone constructive.